# ValueError: A target array with shape (60000, 28, 28, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 28, 28, 128)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm making an Autoencoder in Keras and Tensorflow and I keep running into the below error. I think it's a problem to do with my model architecture and how the dimensions of the input are transformed when passed in the encoder and decoder. 
Error Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-4f4e153bd0cf> in <module>()
     48 
     49 autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3), loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
---> 50 autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=50, batch_size = 256, shuffle= True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
     51 encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
     52 decoder_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    707         steps=steps_per_epoch,
    708         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 709         shuffle=shuffle)
    710 
    711     # Prepare validation data.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2690           # Additional checks to avoid users mistakenly using improper loss fns.
   2691           training_utils.check_loss_and_target_compatibility(
-> 2692               y, self._feed_loss_fns, feed_output_shapes)
   2693 
   2694       # If sample weight mode has not been set and weights are None for all the

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_loss_and_target_compatibility(targets, loss_fns, output_shapes)
    547           raise ValueError('A target array with shape ' + str(y.shape) +
    548                            ' was passed for an output of shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 549                            ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
    550                            'This loss expects targets to have the same shape '
    551                            'as the output.')

ValueError: A target array with shape (60000, 28, 28, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 28, 28, 128) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Here is my code: Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K 
(x_train, x_train), (x_test, x_test) = mnist.load_data()

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
# x_train = x_train.reshape(6000, 28, 28, 1)   
# x_test = x_test.reshape(6000,28, 28, 1)

x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1), np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

encoder_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3,activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomUniform)(encoder_img)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3,activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
encoder_output = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

#Spatial sparsity -
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_img, outputs=encoder_output, name = 'encoder')
encoder.summary()

decoder_input = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((20, 20, 16))(encoder_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation = 'relu')(decoder_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(1)(x) 
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(1)(x)
decoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)

autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs = encoder_img, outputs = decoder_output, name='autoencoder')
autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3), loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=50, batch_size = 256, shuffle= True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoder_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

New Error with below as replacement

```
decoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-cbc6c54cd473> in <module>()
     48 
     49 autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3), loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
---> 50 autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=50, batch_size = 256, shuffle= True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
     51 encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
     52 decoder_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 4096 values, but the requested shape has 1638400
     [[{{node reshape_56/Reshape}}]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You have an autoencoder model which produces a `<batchxheightxwidthxchannels>` output. But during `fit()` you are trying to fit the model with some categorical targets (seems like binary labels). To me, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're right. It's been updated. @thushv89

Comment: You're using an input of size `28x28x1`. But the final layer of your decoder is producing an output of `28x28x128`? Can you check if the error goes away if you change the last line as, `tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)`?

Comment: Yes it did, could you explain why that worked please. Thank you @thushv89

Comment: There's a new error: ```InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 4096 values, but the requested shape has 1638400
  [[{{node reshape_56/Reshape}}]]


```

Comment: I've posted it in the post too.

Comment: So you are essentially trying to reconstruct the input image right? Which is a 28x28x1. So your targets are actually of that size. But before, you had a ConvTranspose layer that produced a 28x28x128 output. So your targets and the model output didn't match. Thus the error.

Comment: The new error looks like something wrong with your data. Can you check the shape of your data (x_train) and verify it is in fact `<dataset_size x 28 x 28 x 1>`?

Comment: x_train is size (6000, 1) - I'll resize it. Thank you.